# multiple images inside one large CSV file

Tags: image-segmentation, csv

I'm very new to data science, and was admiring how people had made these massive open-source datasets, on places like kaggle. I noticed that all of the datasets where all in CSV format. I have lots of images that I'd like to upload to kaggle for everyone to use, although don't know how to convert my images to CSV. (I can't upload them as individual images because there is a limit of 1000 files, which is not enough for a lot of small images).

Thanks in advance,
Tom

P.S. The simpler the explanation the better. I've got some experience in python but not in this area.

Comment: The image datasets are definitely not all in csv format, see for example [this computer vision dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/crowww/a-large-scale-fish-dataset). I would therefore just use the original image format instead of converting the image data to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is you can place all the images on public drive accesible to everyone. In the csv file share the path of the file as one field with all other details. this should work.

You cannot load 1000s of images in csv it should be refernce to path of the images